# What is a bit_expr in mysql grammar?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, flex-lexer

I have been trying to create a MySQL lexical analyzer and parser for my school project and the grammar I have gotten. Some of it goes like this:

```
expr:
expr OR expr
| expr || expr
| expr XOR expr
| expr AND expr
| expr && expr
| NOT expr
| ! expr
| boolean_primary IS [NOT] {TRUE | FALSE | UNKNOWN}
| boolean_primary

boolean_primary:
boolean_primary IS [NOT] NULL
| boolean_primary <=> predicate
| boolean_primary comparison_operator predicate
| boolean_primary comparison_operator {ALL | ANY} (subquery)
| predicate

comparison_operator: = | >= | > | <= | < | <> | !=

predicate:
bit_expr [NOT] IN (subquery)
| bit_expr [NOT] IN (expr [, expr] ...)
| bit_expr [NOT] BETWEEN bit_expr AND predicate
| bit_expr SOUNDS LIKE bit_expr
| bit_expr [NOT] LIKE simple_expr [ESCAPE simple_expr]
| bit_expr [NOT] REGEXP bit_expr
| bit_expr

 bit_expr:
 bit_expr | bit_expr
| bit_expr & bit_expr
| bit_expr << bit_expr
| bit_expr >> bit_expr
| bit_expr + bit_expr
| bit_expr - bit_expr
| bit_expr * bit_expr
| bit_expr / bit_expr
| bit_expr DIV bit_expr
| bit_expr MOD bit_expr
| bit_expr % bit_expr
| bit_expr ^ bit_expr
| bit_expr + interval_expr
| bit_expr - interval_expr
| simple_expr

 simple_expr:
 literal
| identifier
| function_call
| simple_expr COLLATE collation_name
| param_marker
| variable
| simple_expr || simple_expr
| + simple_expr
| - simple_expr
| ~ simple_expr
| ! simple_expr
| BINARY simple_expr
| (expr [, expr] ...)
| ROW (expr, expr [, expr] ...)
| (subquery)
| EXISTS (subquery)
| {identifier expr}
| match_expr
| case_expr
| interval
```

What does `bit_expr` stands for? If possible, can I get a MySQL syntax situation where `bit_expr` is replaced by whatever it is as an example code?

Comment: The given definition describes what it is.  What about that description is unclear?

Comment: can you give me an example of usage of that grammar in a mysql code line?

Comment: I don't see `bit_exprn` in the grammar, I only see `bit_expr`. It's short for "bit expression".

Comment: I'm not sure what "bit" means in that, since these expressions are not necessarily just bit-wise operators. I think it's just an arbitrary name someone came up for this level in the hierarchy of expression parsing.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple example:

```
select 0b01 & 0b10, 0b01 | 0b10 from dual
```

returns

```
0, 3
```